# How to use shared assets between react and react-native in nx project

Tags: typescript, react-native, monorepo, nrwl-nx, nx-monorepo

I have been using Nx with angular but now decided to migrate to reactjs and react-native. I have tried different answers to share images from the shared library to my react native app. This does not seem to be feasible.

Is there anybody who has successfully shared assets between react-native apps, e.g.

```
apps
  - web
  - mobile
  - server
libs
  - shared-assets
```

I tried adding assets to
`"assets": { "glob": "**/*", "input": "libs/assets/src/lib/", "output": "/assets/" }`
in my project.json

Comment: Do you use vite to build the web app? Im trying something similar but seems the assets option of the @nx/vite:build is not there

Comment: Sorry for delay response. I am using vite. Did you succeed?